# How to copy the path of image and store it in? Error:- The method copy isnt defined fo type 'PickedFile'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image

This is the error when using the copy function. How do I save the image  clicked from the camera?

[image]

```
Future _takePicture() async {
    final imageFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      maxHeight: 600,
    );
    setState(() {
      _storedImage = File(imageFile.path);
    });
    final appDir = await syspaths.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final fileName = path.basename(imageFile.path);
    final savedImage = await imageFile.copy('${appDir.path}/$fileName');
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

you should copy `_storedImage` instead of `imageFile`

`imageFile` type is `PickedFile` and hasn't `copy` method

```
Future _takePicture() async {
        final imageFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(
          source: ImageSource.camera,
          maxHeight: 600,
        );
        setState(() {
          _storedImage = File(imageFile.path);
        });
        final appDir = await syspaths.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        final fileName = path.basename(imageFile.path);
        final savedImage = await _storedImage.copy('${appDir.path}/$fileName');
      }
```